# Validar strings com muitos zeros

Tags: sql-server

Tenho que efetuar uma validação em uma trigger no sql server a regra é:
se o cnpj for !=0 e não existir em outro registro continue;

porem o cnpj pode vir com 0 ou 000 ou 0000000 ou 00, que daria no mesmo...

atualmente estou fazendo a validação abaixo porem, pediram para que eu mudasse a validação !=0 para alguma coisa mais "elegante", alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

```
 IF 0 != CONVERT(bigint,(SELECT CGC_CPF FROM inserted)) 
  BEGIN 
    if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CADASTRO_CLI_FOR A 
                  LEFT JOIN FILIAIS B ON A.COD_CLIFOR=B.COD_FILIAL 
                        WHERE A.CGC_CPF=@CNPJ
                        AND B.INDICA_ARMAZEM =0)
  begin
      select @errno  = 30002,
             @errmsg = 'Impossível Incluir #FORNECEDORES #porque CNPJ #ja existe.'
      goto error
    end
  end

  return
```

Comment: Caso na tabela INSERTED exista mais de uma linha, ocorerá erro no procedimento de gatilho. Sugestão de leitura: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/38010.armadilhas-na-programacao-de-procedimentos-de-gatilho.aspx

Comment: Poderia postar o código do procedimento de gatilho? // O que seria "mais elegante"?

Comment: a trigger é bem grande mais essa é a parte onde preciso refatorar. Mais elegante seria uma maneira melhor de fazer este teste;

Comment: Entendi a questão do insert com mais linhas, mas como preciso pegar o cnpj da INSERTED devo fazer um laço para validar todas as linhas? pois teria que validar todas as linhas no INSERTED, ou teira outra solução?

Comment: A validação não poderia ser feita na aplicação? // Qual a origem do conteúdo da variável @CNPJ?

Comment: Infelizmente não, o software é de terceiros, e temos mais de um software persistindo no mesmo banco e alguns são softwares legados sem esta regra, eles poderiam burlar esta validação, por este motivo precisamos aplicar diretamente no DB

Comment: CONSIDERANDO-SE: (1) a necessidade de que procedimento de gatilho trate mais de uma linha; (2) que o atual procedimento de gatilho está programado para tratar somente uma linha por vez; (3) a impossibilidade de sugerir solução set-based pelo desconhecimento (de minha parte) do código fonte do procedimento de gatilho; AVALIE a implementação da solução “Simulação for each row com cursor” proposta em https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/40005.armadilhas-na-programacao-de-procedimentos-de-gatilho-caso-4.aspx // Altere-a para a tabela INSERTED.